# html link onclick pop up a form

Tags: javascript, html

i'd like to pop up a form when click a link.

```
<a title='%s' onclick='return popupform()'  href='#'> ABC </a>
```

the form is like:

```
<form id="contactus" action="javascript:submit_form()" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="1">
    <label for="chinese">Chinese: </label><br>
    <input type="text" name="cs" id="cs" value="" maxlength="50"><br>
<label for="english">English:</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="en" id="en" value="" maxlength="50"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Save" value="Save">
    <input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete">
    <input type="submit" name="Add" value="Add">
    <input type="submit" name="Close" value="Close">
</form>
```

how to achieve  it?

Comment: i suggest you to use jquery-ui dialog.

Comment: fancybox.net would be another jQuery plugin that could achieve this, a bit more lightweight imo. Or you could write verything from scratch with jQuery and css, should not be that hard... What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `form` in a `div`:

```
<a title="%s" class="show_form" href="#"> ABC </a>

<div id="form_wrapper">
    <form id="contactus" action="javascript:submit_form()" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    ... truncated for brevity
    </form>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

And some CSS:

```
​#form_wrapper {
    display:none;
}​
```

And then some JavaScript using jQuery:

```
$('a.show_form').on('click', function() {
    $('#form_wrapper').show();
});​​​​​
```

And if you really mean a popup window, or commonly called a "modal" window, look here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Comment: thanks, the  jquery func i test  seems has has inlegal token. <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('a.show_form').on('click', function() {
    $('#form_wrapper').show();
  });​​​​​
</script>

Comment: It lloks like you have some weird invisible characters after the very last `});`. Could be from copying and pasting from my example. Try deleting all the whitespace at the end of each line you copied from my example.

And if you're still stuck, if you're using Chrome, click on the actual error in the developer console and it should show you specifically what is causing the error. That's how I saw the invisible characters.

Comment: i'm newbie with jQuery, anyhow it works below:  $(document).ready(function(){  $("a.show_form").click(function(){    $('#form_wrapper').show();
  });
});

Answer (score 1):

Pop-ups are simple div elements on the page that would be initially hidden and then revealed when some event takes place, like a mouse click.  You then need to adjust the look of that div so it appears as a pop-up to the user, i.e. center the div on the page, raise its z-index so it layers above all, adjust the opacity to give the dimming effect, and so on.  Obviously it is a lot of work if you decide to roll your own. Otherwise, if you are OK with using [jquery](http://jquery.com), you can take advantage of the [jqueryui dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) element

Comment: <dialog> tag is added in html5